# histogram of signals gaps width (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, signals, histogram

I am looking for algorithm (effective + vectorized) how to find histogram of gaps (NaN) width in the following manner:

1. signals are represented by (Nsamples x Nsig) array
2. gaps in signal are encoded by NaN's
3. width of gaps: is number of consecutive NaN's in the signal
4. gaps width histogram: is frequency of gaps with specific widths in signals

And the following conditions are fullfilled:

```
[Nsamples,Nsig ]= size(signals)
isequal(size(signals),size(gapwidthhist)) % true
isequal(sum(gapwidthhist.*(1:Nsamples)',1),sum(isnan(signals),1)) % true
```

Of course, compressed form of  gapwidthhist (represented by two cells: "gapwidthhist_compressed_widths" and "gapwidthhist_compressed_freqs") is required too.

Example:

```
signals = [1.1 NaN NaN NaN  -1.4 NaN 8.3 NaN NaN NaN  NaN 1.5 NaN NaN; % signal No. 1
           NaN 2.2 NaN 4.9   NaN 8.2 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN 2.4 NaN NaN]' % signal No. 2
gapwidthhist = [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; % gap histogram for signal No. 1
                3 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]' % gap histogram for signal No. 2
```

where integer histogram bins (gap widths) are 1:Nsamples (Nsamples=14).

Coresponding compressed gap histogram looks like:

```
gapwidthhist_compressed_widths =  cell(1,Nsig)
gapwidthhist_compressed_widths =
  1×2 cell array
    {[1 2 3 4]}    {[1 2 5]}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
gapwidthhist_compressed_freqs = cell(1, Nsig)
gapwidthhist_compressed_freqs =
  1×2 cell array
    {[1 1 1 1]}    {[3 1 1]}
```

Typical problem dimension:

```
Nsamples = 1e5 - 1e6
Nsig = 1e2 - 1e3.
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Added remark:** My so far best solution is the following code:

```
signals = [1.1 NaN NaN NaN  -1.4 NaN 8.3 NaN NaN NaN  NaN 1.5 NaN NaN; % signal No. 1
           NaN 2.2 NaN 4.9   NaN 8.2 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN 2.4 NaN NaN; % signal No. 2
           1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN]' % signal No. 3
[numData, numSignals] = size(signals)
gapwidthhist = zeros(numData, numSignals);
for column = 1 : numSignals
    thisSignal = signals(:, column); % Extract this column.
    % Find lengths of all NAN runs
    props = regionprops(isnan(thisSignal), 'Area');
    allLengths = [props.Area]
    edges = [1:max(allLengths), inf]
    hc = histcounts(allLengths, edges)
    % Load up gapwidthhist
    for k2 = 1 : length(hc)
        gapwidthhist(k2, column) = hc(k2);
    end
end
% What it is:
gapwidthhist'
```

But I am looking mainly for pure Matlab code without any built-in matlab functions (like "regionprops" from Image Processing Toolbox)!!!

Comment: Why not loop through the elements of the column; if the element is NaN, increment a counter; if the element is non-NaN, save the count and reset the counter.

Comment: @beaker could you elaborate your method in more details?

Answer (score 1):

This is much more simple Matlab implementation but still not optimal (+ not vectorized):

```
signals = [1.1 NaN NaN NaN  -1.4 NaN 8.3 NaN NaN NaN  NaN 1.5 NaN NaN; % signal No. 1
    NaN 2.2 NaN 4.9   NaN 8.2 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN 2.4 NaN NaN; % signal No. 2
        1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN]';  % signal No. 3
signals
[numData, numSignals] = size(signals);
gapwidthhist = zeros(numData, numSignals);
gaps = zeros(numData+1,numSignals);
auxnan = isnan(signals);
for i = 1:numSignals
    c = 0;
    for j = 1:numData
        if auxnan(j,i)
            c = c + 1;
        else
            gaps(j,i) = c;
            c = 0;
        end
    end
    gaps(numData+1,i) = c;
    gapwidthhist(:,i) = histcounts(gaps(:,i),1:numData+1);
end
gapwidthhist
```

Thanks to @breaker for help.

**Any idea how to optimize (vectorize) this code to be more effective?**

Comment: In what way is this not optimal? The time complexity is *O(n)*, which is the minimum possible because you have to examine all of the elements of the array. What is the size of your actual data? What is the execution time of your script on that data?

Comment: From good Matlab programming point of view is this code still not optimal: 1) gaps array is used very memory ineffective, 2) each signals column processing is completely independent, so potential parallelization of outer loop with parfor-loop should be possible, but now it does not. 3) Calling of histcounts function at outer loop should be eliminated, and gapwidthhist(:,i) should be computed directly in inner loop. 4) numData = 1e6
numSignals = 1e3.

Comment: 5) code is serial (one core run only). Execution time: numData = 1e5 numSignals = 1e3: 3.7sec, Execution time: numData = 1e6 numSignals = 1e2: 6.7sec

Comment: Execution time strongly depend on number of NaN's at signals!

Comment: Ah, I missed that you were still using `histcounts`. Yeah, don't do that. Change the inner `else` clause to `gapwidthhist(c,i) = gapwidthhist(c,i) + 1; c = 0;` Now there's no need for the `gaps` array.

Comment: Incidentally, if those are your concerns, they should all be stated in the question. It is also unclear what you consider `built-in` functions. For instance, is `accumarray` considered a built-in?

Comment: gapwidthhist(c,i) = gapwidthhist(c,i) + 1; does not work in a case c = 0.

Comment: yup :) do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more vectorized version that may be a bit quicker. I use Octave, so I don't know how much MATLAB's JIT compiler will optimize the inner loop in the other approach.

```matlab
% Set up the data
signals = [1.1 NaN NaN NaN  -1.4 NaN 8.3 NaN NaN NaN  NaN 1.5 NaN NaN; % signal No. 1
    NaN 2.2 NaN 4.9   NaN 8.2 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN 2.4 NaN NaN; % signal No. 2
        1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN]';  % signal No. 3
signals
[numData, numSignals] = size(signals);
gapwidthhist = zeros(numData, numSignals);
gaps = zeros(numData+1,numSignals);
auxnan = ~isnan(signals);   % We want non-NaN values to be 1

for i = 1:numSignals
   difflist = diff(find([1; auxnan(:,i); 1])) - 1;   % get the gap lengths
   gapList = difflist(find(difflist));   % keep only the non-zero gaps
   for c = gapList.'                     % need row vector to loop over elements
      gapwidthhist(c,i) = gapwidthhist(c,i) + 1;   % each gap length increments the histogram
   end
end

gapwidthhist
```

Here's the program flow:

- First, negate the `auxnan` array so that NaN is 0 and non-NaN is 1.
- In the outer loop, pad each column with 1's on top and bottom to capture strings of NaN at the beginning and end of the signal.
- Use `find` to get the indices of the 1 (non-NaN) elements.
- Take the `diff` of the indices.
- A `diff` of 1 means no gap and a `diff` greater than 1 gives the length of the gap *plus* 1, so subtract 1 from the `diff` result.
- Use the results (indices) of `find` to get the values of the nonzero elements. These are the gap widths.
- Now loop through the values and accumulate the results in the histogram. You might try replacing this inner loop with `accumarray` to see if that speeds things up any.

Answer (score 0):

May be final solution:

```
signals = [1.1 NaN NaN NaN  -1.4 NaN 8.3 NaN NaN NaN  NaN 1.5 NaN NaN; % signal No. 1
    NaN 2.2 NaN 4.9   NaN 8.2 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN 2.4 NaN NaN; % signal No. 2
        1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN]';  % signal No. 3

signals

[numData, numSignals] = size(signals);
gapwidthhist = zeros(numData, numSignals);
auxnan = isnan(signals);
for i = 1:numSignals
    c = 0;
    for j = 1:numData
        if auxnan(j,i)
            c = c + 1;
        else
            if c > 0
                gapwidthhist(c,i) = gapwidthhist(c,i) + 1;
                c = 0;
            end
        end
    end
    if c > 0
        gapwidthhist(c,i) = gapwidthhist(c,i) + 1;
    end
end

gapwidthhist
```

**Open question:** how to modify the code where outer for-loop should be able to use parfor-loop?